# Drizzle-ORM return size of findMany

Tags: sql, typescript, drizzle

Hi im trying out the Drizzle ORM and

lets say i have this query

```
const players = await trx.query.playerTable.findMany({
  with: {
   posts:true
  }
})
```

how can get the number of players in that query?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the wrong function to get the number of players.
The `findMany` is used to get the records.
So if you want to get the number of players it would be like `players.lenght` (that is the attribute of the array got from the query).
I suggest to use the `select` with the aggregate functions if you just want the number of records.
Look at this link as reference, hope it helps. https://orm.drizzle.team/docs/select#aggregations